# Can anyone help me understand why my arguments don't trigger when Session variable changes with React?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to toggle between an active and inactive button based on whether or not the Session variable is `true` or `false`.

On a child component, I declare the Session variable:

```
  choice(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  ...
    Session.set("upNext", true);
   ...

  };
```

Then, on the parent component, I place this code in the render(){} function:

```
render(){

let upNext;
if(Session.get("upNext")){
upNext = <button className="ui right huge labeled icon primary button" onClick={this.nextPosition.bind(this)}><i className="right arrow icon"></i>Next</button>
} else{
upNext = <button className="ui right huge labeled icon primary button disabled" onClick={this.nextPosition.bind(this)}><i className="right arrow icon"></i>Next</button>
}

  return(
    <div className="ui container">
      {upNext}
    </div>
  }
```

Finally, in the `componentWillMount()` method, I set the Session variable to `false` to reset before the next component loads.

The Session variable triggers, changes from false to true, but the code inside the first conditional (if Session.get is equal to true) never gets run. Never had this problem happen when working with Blaze, so there must be something here that I'm completely missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have just decided to solve this problem with good old javascript and manipulated the `className` attribute after button click myself rather than depend on the Session variable.

Still, it's kind of strange as to why the Sessions are behaving weird with React.

Comment: You could've set the session value to a reactive variable in your component container, so when it changes it triggers a change in the props of your component, hence causing the render function to be called again.

Comment: I used ReactiveVar instead of Session variables in the `createContainer` component and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parts of your code that need to be reactive to within `createContainer` - https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer

Comment: I used ReactiveVar instead of Session variables in the `createContainer` component and it worked. Session variable doesn't work no matter what I do.